# how to optimize a wordlist for the english language

Tags: regex, linux, string, text, sed

i'm looking to optimize a wordlist for the english language using sed or a similar linux application.. in order to do this i need to:

Remove lines containing anything except a-z, 0-9, or special characters

Remove urls - maybe detection of the "\" character

Remove lines over 16 characters long, and 4 characters or shorter. (5-16 chars)

Preferably in sed =)

Thanks!

Comment: You can use http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ in the future for building regexs. Plus, using it will teach how to make them from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -nr '/^[[:alnum:]]{5,16}$/p' words
```

- `-n` means don't print lines by default
- `-r` means use 'extended' regular expressions

The sed command is:

- `/.../` when we have a something that matches

  - `^...$` a whole line consisting of only

    - `[...]` the character class of:

      - `[:alnum:]` alphanumeric characters
    - `{5,16}` between 5 and 16 times
- `p` then we print it

Comment: is there a way to include custom characters as well?

Comment: Just include them in the character class, e.g.: `[[:alnum:]{}+&%]`

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne "print if /^[a-zA-Z0-9{other allowed characters here}]{4,16}$/"
```

Comment: is there any way to do this in sed?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Anon.:

```
egrep '^[a-zA-Z0-9{other allowed characters here}]{4,16}$'
```

Comment: is there any way to do this in sed?